# Transfer variable from one to another function in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel at this time to secure a page when a user enters their password on a modal form before it opens. I initialized a variable named `$crypt`, which is hidden in the form, to make every page unique (to prevent other people from opening the page with a URL).

I want to pass the `$crypt` data to the PDFView. How can I do that? I've tried a lot of things but none worked.

**Error**

> Undefined variable: crypts

Route:

```
Route::get('/pdfview/{id}/', 'HomeController@pdfview')->name('pdfview');
```

**Generated key code**

```
<div style="display: none">{{ $crypt = str_random(10)}}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function encryptslip(Request $request, $crypt)
{
    $crypts = $crypt;
    $id = $request->nip;
    $pass = $request->password;
    $nip = Auth::user()->nip;
    if (Hash::check($pass, Auth::user()->password)) {
        return redirect('/pdfview/' . $nip . '/', ['crypts' => $crypts])->with('crypt', $crypt);
    } else {
        return redirect('/home')->with('alert', 'Incorrect password');
    }
}

    public function pdfview(Request $request, $id)
    {



    $route = url()->current();
        $month = Carbon::now()->month;
        $periodeinput = DB::table('payrollinput')->where('nip', '=', $id)->orderBy('periode', 'desc')->pluck('periode')->implode('periode');
        $periodehistory = DB::table('payrollhistory')->where('nip', '=', $id)->orderBy('periode', 'desc')->pluck('periode')->implode('periode');
//        if ($periodeinput !== $month && $periodehistory !== $month) {
//            return redirect('home')->with('alert', 'Slip gaji anda siap.');
//        } else {
        if (Auth::user()->nip == $id) {
            $employees = MasterEmployee::where('nip', '=', $id)->first();
            $payrollhistory = MasterPayrollHistory::where('nip', '=', $id)->where('periode', '=', $month)->first();
            $payrollinput = MasterPayrollInput::where('nip', '=', $id)->where('periode', '=', $month)->first();
            view()->share('employees', $employees);
            view()->share('payrollhistory', $payrollhistory);
            view()->share('payrollinput', $payrollinput);
            view()->share('id', $id);

           // calculation code
            return view('pdfview', ['id' => $id])->with('id', $id)
                ->with('earningtotal', $earningtotal)
                ->with('deductiontotal', $deductiontotal)
                ->with('takehomepay', $takehomepay)
                ->with('total', $total);
        } else {

            return redirect('home')->with('alert', 'Sorry it is personally confidential, you are not able to see it.');
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div><{{$crypts}}</div>
```

Comment: Assuming you've formatted your code correctly, you've got blade trying to parse a variable inside of </div> closing tag. That won't work.

Comment: Sorry it was typo, thanks for your attention, I edited it again. But it was closed properly inside my code. In my case I got Undefined variable: crypts

Comment: In your controller, `code return to pdfview.blade.php` could we see the actual code that returns the view?

Comment: @Adam sure, just edited

Answer (score 1):

when you use `return redirect()` method that variable is passed to the view as a `session` variable and in the `blade` it must be called form

`<div>{{session('crypts')}}</div>`

to convert this `session` variable on `$request`

`{{Form:hidden('crypts', json_encode(session('crypts'))}}`

Comment: thank you very much, that really helps my understanding.
if it's a session then it will be flushed after i refresh the page right?
how do i pass the variable without putting it inside the url/route?

Comment: yes, if you refresh oage this `session` delete, to pass this session need create one `form::hidden` and put one `json_encode`